# Generics T based parser for different properties within a string

Tags: c#, generics, refactoring

I have a feed coming which has different properties serialized as comma separated values

```
feed = "[{"HIGH", "[235.76, 235.96, 235.97]"}, 
         {"LOW", "[235.76, 235.96, 235.97'"}, 
         {"DATE", "[20170410-10:21:34, 20170410-10:31:34, 20170410-10:43:34, 20170410-10:59:34]" }  .....
        ]"
```

I have a business need to create an entity out of this containing different properties for each of HIGH /LOW /Date etc. Now "High" and Low will be of double whereas Date will be of dateTime type. 
I am splitting the string following each tag and then parsing each value to the corresponding property.

However since the property's datatype differ, I require a parse function for each type.

```
private void GetFeedData(string[] data, List<int> field)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < data.Length; i++)
        {
            **int fieldValue = int.Parse(data[i]);**
            field.Add(fieldValue);
        }
    }
```

I have ended up with different functions, one specific to each datatype, differing in just the parsing of **fieldValue**

I am want to do something like this, but this doesn't seem to be supported.

```
private void GetFeedData<T>(string[] data, List<T> field) where T: struct
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < data.Length; i++)
        {
            T fieldValue = (T)(data[i]);
            field.Add(fieldValue);
        }
    }
```

This will be a single method for all types, which will be a lot easier. Not sure how to achieve this.. Please help

Comment: Using generics doesn't let you avoid having to know the type, it just helps you avoid duplicating the same logic once for each type. So , given your example, the call would have to look something like this: `GetFeedData<double>(feed, parsedValues);` and it would still try to parse every value as a double and it would still fail. I think you will have to inspect the values and determine type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this, but I think your example is not syntactically correct.

```
private IList<T> GetFeedData<T>(string[] data) 
{
    List<T> field = new List<T>();

    for (int i = 0; i < data.Length; i++)
    {
        T fieldValue = (T)(Convert.ChangeType(data[i], typeof(T)));
        field.Add(fieldValue);
    }

    return field;
}
```

Comment: This still doesn't fix the issue of having data of different types. See my comment to the OP.

Comment: This works perfect Max. Thanks a lot. I have been able to call this for int/string/double/datetime